# ForeignKey field is going NULL in django, why?

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have this code:

```
if formPedido.is_valid() and formsetItens.is_valid():

        my_db_alias = profile.dbname
        cursor = connections[my_db_alias].cursor()

        cursor.execute('select id_retorno from prc_sequenciadora(' + str(profile.idempresa) + ', %s, %s, 0, 0)', ('VENDA_PEDIDO', 'IDVENDA_PEDIDO'))# calls PROCEDURE named LOG_MESSAGE which resides in MY_UTIL Package
        res = cursor.fetchone()
        transaction.commit_unless_managed(using=profile.dbname)

        idvendapedido = res[0]

        pedido = formPedido.save(commit=False)
        itens = formsetItens.save(commit=False)


        pedido.idpedido = idvendapedido
        pedido.idrepresentante = profile.id_comerx3c # passando o id do representante
        pedido.idempresa = profile.idempresa # passando o id da empresa
        pedido.idtabpreco = profile.idtabela_preco # passando o id da tabela de preco usada
        pedido.programado = 'S'
        pedido.internet = 'S'

        for forms in itens:
            forms.idempresa = profile.idempresa # passando o id da empresa
            forms.idvenda_pedido_itens = -1
            forms.idvenda_pedido = pedido
            forms.internet = 'S'
```

I need to pass the "pedido" instance to my itens.idvenda_pedido... the itens.idvenda_pedido is a ForeignKey to Pedido model.

in this line I get the new integer value: **pedido.idpedido = idvendapedido**   but this new value doens't go to my "itens"

How can I do these? I can't use AutoField because I need to use a stored procedure to get my value...

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Are you save each form in "for forms in itens" iteration?

Comment: You could try in "for forms in itens" iteration:  
`iten_instance = form.save(commit=False)  `  
`iten_instance.idvenda_pedido_itens = -1  `  
`iten_instance.idvenda_pedido = pedido  `  
`iten_instance.internet = 'S'  `  
`iten_instance.save()  `